# I do not seem to be post-banned on Stack Overflow, but I still cannot ask a question

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, notifications, posting

I would like to ask a question on Stack Overflow, but the site does **not** tell me why I cannot post a question there. If I click on the the button `Post Your Question`, nothing happens. I do **not** get a message like "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account".

So, what is the reason then? Is this a bug?

Comment: Do you get an error message? Do you have any userscripts installed that might be blocking the submission?

Comment: @bluefeet I am using NoScript, but I deactivated it – and I still do not get a message. Also, I have used another browser. Still nothing.

Comment: What browser, version, operating system are you using?  If you open Dev Tools, do you have any errors?

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's developer console to make sure there are no JavaScript errors? This can happen if you the JS file failed to load for whatever reason. Have you tried a hard refresh?

Comment: @bluefeet I have used the latest Firefox and the Internet Explorer (which I avoid using) on a Windows 7 Professional 64 bit operating system.

@animuson I have opened the console and can see `GET XHR https://stackoverflow.com/posts/new-tags-warning` and `POST XHR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/submit`. But I have **not** used any new tags. And I have already tried a hard refresh. New tabs; alternative browser.

Comment: Now it works again. The problem seems to be solved. But I don’t know why or how.

Comment: Another user reported something similar on MSO earlier. The question was deleted, but I think [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359954/curiosity-cant-post-a-question-cross-browser) is the right link.

Comment: @Laurel The page cannot be found because it was removed.

Comment: @Nemgathos It works for moderators and anyone with 10k rep on StackOverflow.

Comment: Here is a  bug report: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359997/new-tags-warning-when-trying-to-ask-a-question-is-not-shown /cc @animuson